# bind9 insecurity proof failed resolving

Tags: dns, bind

i have 2 ubuntu servers and bind9 installed on both of them.

this are the configurations of the first one:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    forwarders {
        1.1.1.1;
    };
    dnssec-validation auto;
};

zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.example.com";
};

$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA dns-srv. root.dns-srv. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  dns-srv.
@   IN  A   172.16.194.4
www IN  A   172.16.194.4
```

these are the configurations of the second one:

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        forwarders {
                172.16.194.3;
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
};
```

so the first dns server forwards requests to 1.1.1.1 and the second dns server forwards requests to the first dns server 172.16.194.3.

i have no issues querying names from the public dns on the first server and no issues forwarding queries to the second server. it works. every host that uses the second dns server can query and get replies.
the problem is with the zone "example.com" that is defined on the first dns server.
when the second dns server queries the first dns server for "example.com" i get the error: `insecurity proof failed resolving 'example.com/A/IN': 172.16.194.3#53`

why do i get this error and what do i have to do to make the second dns server resolve zones that are defined on the first dns server ?

on both servers the os is ubuntu server 20.4 and bind version is 9.16

Comment: Is the problematic zone _literally_ named `example.com`? It's going to matter here.

Comment: yes it is. for the sake of this post. before it had another name (something else dot com) and i faced the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why do i get this error

Because you're tampering with a DNSSEC-signed zone. In this case, the error message is normal, as you're doing exactly something that DNSSEC is supposed to prevent.

The *real* `example.com` zone on the Internet is DNSSEC-signed, and the parent `com` zone has DS records indicating its signing key (alongside the usual NS records for delegation). When the validating resolver on Server#2 finds those DS records, it knows that it's supposed to receive signed data for example.com, and therefore the unsigned records it's getting from your Server#1 is unauthorized.

("Proof of non-existence" refers to NSEC records that the `com` zone would have for actually unsigned zones – an NSEC record basically says "there are records of exactly these types and no others", in this case it would be used to prove that there's no DS record for a legitimately unsigned zone.)

> what do i have to do to make the second dns server resolve zones that are defined on the first dns server ?

First, don't use zone names belonging to someone else. Use your own domain name that you control – one that you could just publish an actual NS delegation for.

Even if you can't actually delegate the domain to Server#1 for some reason, still make sure it's delegated to *some* nameservers (i.e. that there are NS records), so that resolvers will be able to get the NSEC answer they want. It doesn't matter where the delegation points, the validator only checks DS records, not NS.

(The `home.arpa` domain name has been set up this way – it's specifically meant to be "overridden" by home gateways, so you can use it as an example for how to set up your own (sub)domain that's safe to override.)

Finally, if it has to be a name that's completely out of your control (e.g. if you want to actually use `example.com`, or if you want to make a whole TLD like `.blah`), you could *actually DNSSEC-sign it yourself* and configure the key as a "trust anchor" directly in your resolver. The validation process goes upwards until it finds a trust anchor – typically it reaches all the way to the root, but BIND allows you to configure `trust-anchors{}` for any domain you need.

Some validating resolvers also support "negative trust anchors" that let you manually configure some domains as never validated, but in BIND this is only supported as an auto-expiring setting via `rndc nta` and not something you could put in the config file permanently.

Comment: thank you. i signed the zone. now i have on server#1 2 key pairs and a .signed zone file. when i use dig @server#1 +dnssec i get a valid signed response with rrsig records.
i dont really know how to add trusted-anchor. which key do i have to add in server#2 bind.keys file ? the zsk or the ksk ? and in what format ? unfortunately it is very hard to find onlive references for this issue.

Comment: never mind. i got it. i needed to add 'static-key' after the domain in the bind.keys and to set 'dnssec-validation yes' in the options file.

Comment: Usually the KSK is the trust anchor (just like when setting up real DNSSEC delegations at your registrar, the DS records point to the KSK) – the purpose of separate KSK/ZSK is so that the ZSK can be updated without needing to reconfigure all trust anchors (or DS records). Some format examples are at https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_18_0/advanced.html#configuring-servers-for-dnssec and at https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9_18_0/dnssec-guide.html#trusted-keys-and-managed-keys (the latter only has an example of `.` i.e. root zone, but you can fill in your domain instead).

Comment: well that was a good lesson on dnssec. i had to dive into it and now i understand it. one more thing i understand :) but do everyone seriously have to get through all this mess if he wants his local dns server to override signed or non-existent zones ? when i used the same server#1 as a forwarder for windows server it resolved everything and never complained about dnssec. in windows server dns i can turn dnssec on and off. cant i with bind9 ?

Comment: I mean, that's literally DNSSEC doing its job – the resolver on server#2 can't tell legitimate overrides from malicious ones unless you tell it they're legitimate. Per-zone, BIND does not support permanent negative trust anchors, only [time-limited ones](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01418) (`rndc nta -lifetime 1w example.com`), although Unbound and systemd-resolved support that. Globally, that's the "dnssec-validation" option...

Comment: If you're only trying to override specific parts (and especially if you're doing it for a whole lot of domains), you might have better luck configuring server#2 to use a "RPZ" (response policy zone) instead of forwarders. The RPZ feature in BIND supports returning any answer for any name.